# How to access OneDrive’s notification status in C#

Tags: c#, onedrive

**How to access OneDrive’s notification status in C#**

On my Win 7 PC,  OneDrive has an icon in the  Notification / Tool Bar Area .

Hovering over the OneDrive notification icon, I get the following status messages:-

- OneDrive is “up to date”
- OneDrive is “Looking for changes”
- OneDrive is “Uploading 27mb of 346mb, 27 files remaining”

Is it possible to query this status from C#?

I am specifically interested to know when the OneDrive is “up to date” or not.

I would like to write a ShutDown routine for my PC that will check the status of the OneDrive.  If the OneDrive is not “up to date” I can then code a "wait" to provide enough time for any new or changed files to get uploaded to the remote cloud server.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: C# or vb.net, skynet or onedrive? Make up your mind

Comment: I attempted pretty much the same thing with Google Drive, it is one of the few rare occasions i've completely given up and had to take a new approach. It is apparently possible to enumerate the tray icons to do such polling, but i'll be damned if i could get it working. Extreme headache i'm afraid. PS: If anybody does have a solution to this, i'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work for you or not, but take a look at this CodeProject source (it's C++) that enumerates the notification icons and their tooltips. You'll have to figure out how to map that to C#, but if you get the API calls you need to make from the C++ code, you shouldn't have too much trouble mapping them to P/Invoke calls.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10807/Shell-Tray-Info-Arrange-your-system-tray-icons